# how to inject HTML tags in an MX:Text control with a bound text value that renders properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

i am working in a flex application, i have an mx text control or I can use whatever control I need to do display the text value, but what I am trying to accomplish is to be able to format that text value with html 'before' it gets bound to the text control.

```
<mx:Text text="{data.combinedCriteria}" width="99%">
```

In the .as file that manipulates the combinedCriteria property of data, i can do whatever i want, but I haven't found much help out there.

Comment: addendum: I can format it prior to getting there, but it isn't rendering as HTML. The MX: Text control has a MX:htmlText method, but I can't use that since the text is bound at that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried htmlText instead of text?

Comment: yeah, problem with that is, is that thats done in the mxml markup. Once the text value I want to render html in gets to the UI its in an object property and not editable.

Comment: ok, didn't realize that I could use it like that. you are correct.